# Polymorphic variant restriction in the variant definition

Tags: types, ocaml, polymorphic-variants

Suppose that I want to model a simple expression type in OCaml:

```
type expr = 
| `Int of int
| `Str of string
| `IntAdd of expr * expr
| `StrAdd of expr * expr
```

Is it possible to restrict `expr` in `expr * expr` to specific constructors of `expr` itself (i.e. I'd like `IntExpr` to only allow 'Int's)? I can mimic this with pattern 
matching but it gets cumbersome after `expr` expands. Can I somehow 
use OCaml's type system to achieve this?

I tried using polymorphic type upper bounds as follows:

```
type expr = 
| `Int of int
| `Str of string
| `IntAdd of [< `Int] * [< `Int]
| `StrAdd of [< `Str] * [< `Str]
```

but compiler does not accept this (with message `In case IntAdd of [< Int ] * ([< Int ] as 'a) the variable 'a is unbound`). Is there any trick to make this work?

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing you'd use GADTs for in Haskell: `data Expr a where { Int :: Int -> Expr Int; Str :: String -> Expr String; IntAdd :: Expr Int -> Expr Int -> Expr Int; StrAdd :: Expr String -> Expr String -> Expr String }`

Comment: https://mads-hartmann.com/ocaml/2015/01/05/gadt-ocaml.html#the-canonical-example

Comment: Last link really helped a lot---thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given example is simple enough for polymorphic variants to suffice:

```
type int_expr = [`Int of int | `Add of int_expr * int_expr]
type string_expr = [`String of string | `Concat of string_expr * string_expr]
type expr = [int_expr | string_expr]
```

If you want more interesting features like polymorphic data structures, GADTs are necessary:

```
type _ expr =
  | Int : int -> int expr
  | Add : int expr * int expr -> int expr
  | String : string -> string expr
  | Concat : string expr * string expr -> string expr
  | Pair : 'a expr * 'b expr -> ('a * 'b) expr
  | Fst : ('a * 'b) expr -> 'a expr
  | Snd : ('a * 'b) expr -> 'b expr
```

Inference and comprehensibility of error messages suffers with GADTs, so be prepared to work to overcome those difficulties if you decide to use them.

Comment: Thanks--- GADTs seem like a proper way to do this.

Comment: Side note: first example with polymorphic variants does not work as I'd prefer it, as `\`Add(\`String("a"), \`String("b"))` compiles w/o any issues.

Comment: @Ibrahim, of course, polymorphic variants allow unconstrained construction by design. Note that the value you describe will not have type `expr`, and you will get a type error at the point you try to use it as an `expr`, rather than at the point of construction. You can use annotations if you want earlier type checks.